# C# TThreadPoolAsyncServer implementation for Apache Thrift is very very slow

Tags: thrift

In below C# code snippet, you can see how I build a multi-threaded thrift server by using TThreadPoolAsyncServer implementation which is provided by the nuget package (namely C# .NET Core bindings for the Apache Thrift RPC system with version 0.14.1) that is available at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ApacheThrift

I have also implemented a gRPC version of this server implementation and in comparison to gRPC, TThreadPoolAsyncServer's performance is very very low (i.e. slow). I mean my thrift server that is using TThreadPoolAsyncServer can process only a few requests per minute while its gRPC counterpart can process thousands requests. My question is that "Can this be caused by anything I do incorrectly in below code snippet?" Do you think I am particularly missing/overlooking st here, which may cause a serious performance drawback? Many thanks in advance.

```
var serverHandler = new ThriftGatewayServerImpl(xyzInvokerService);

var processor = new ThriftAPIGatewayService.AsyncProcessor(serverHandler);

var protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
var thriftConfiguration = new TConfiguration();                
var serverTransport = new TServerSocketTransport(serverPort, thriftConfiguration);
var transportFactory = new TBufferedTransport.Factory();
var threadConfiguration = new TThreadPoolAsyncServer.Configuration();
var loggerFactory = new SerilogLoggerFactory(Log.Logger);

var server = new TThreadPoolAsyncServer(
     processorFactory: new TSingletonProcessorFactory(processor),
     serverTransport: serverTransport,
     inputTransportFactory: transportFactory,
     outputTransportFactory: transportFactory,
     inputProtocolFactory: protocolFactory,
     outputProtocolFactory: protocolFactory,
     threadConfig: threadConfiguration,
     loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>());                  

var source = new CancellationTokenSource();                  
server.ServeAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
Console.ReadLine();
source.Cancel();
```

Comment: https://thrift.apache.org/mailing

Comment: I have sent an e-mail to thrift user group about the problem that is explained in this post. The link to this e-mail is as follows:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/202105.mbox/browser